# same commit in different repos

Tags: git, github, repo

i'm coding a file in *repo A* and I want to make the same commit in *repo B* (like a backup of this file), is there any git command to do that? (*repo A* is a remote repo and *repo B* is my personal repo)

Comment: Is one a clone of the other? Or are they completely separate repo's?

Comment: they're completely separate

Comment: Why would you want to create a backup repository? Git is version controlled by *design*...

Comment: Short of deleting the entire git repository, you can undo pretty much any operation in git just by going into the git reflog. It keeps a record of all points the HEAD has been in the past 30 days, and you can reset any branch to that point. Run `git reflog` to see it. See here for more: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-reflog

Answer (score 0):

From your local repository `repoB`, you can:

- download the file from the remote `repoA`

  ```
  git archive --remote=ssh://host/pathto/repoA.git HEAD README.md
  ```
- add, commit, and push from `repoB`